# Message Bubbles in Windows with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, notifications

I have a program that have shorcuts etc. and can take and save screenshots. Once a screenshot wís saved, I want to show a notification with bubble like:
[https://tipsfromanand.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/clip_image001.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d52QV.png)

How to do it with Tkinter? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tkinter? No, you can't because the bubble notification is only available  in Windows while all of (most of) tkinter's widgets are meant to be cross-platform. But to do the task, it's very possible with using the `win32api` which is an api for windows. You can get all the modules by using pip to install this package: `pypiwin32` which includes `win32api`, `win32gui`... Here is an example from their source on making the bubble widget you wanted:

```
from win32api import *
from win32gui import *
import win32con
import sys, os
import struct
import time

class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        iconPathName = os.path.abspath(os.path.join( sys.path[0], "balloontip.ico" ))
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
           hicon = LoadImage(hinst, iconPathName, \
                    win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, icon_flags)
        except:
          hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "tooltip")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",title,200,msg))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)
        time.sleep(10)
        DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        UnregisterClass(classAtom, hinst)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.
def balloon_tip(title, msg):
    w=WindowsBalloonTip(msg, title)

balloon_tip('Hello', 'How are you?')
```

If you insist on using tkinter, the closest thing you can get is using tkinter's `messagebox`: Here's a few examples:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox

# hide main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

tkMessageBox.showerror("Error", "Error message")
tkMessageBox.showwarning("Warning","Warning message")
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Information","Informative message")
```

But I would still recommend using the `win32api` since this is what your question's asking for.

**EDIT**

If you're using the first example with tkinter, you will need to first `import threading` then replace `balloon_tip('Hello', 'How are you?')` with this:

```
balloon_thread = threading.Thread(target=balloon_tip, args=('Hello', 'How are you?'))
balloon_thread.start()
```

when trying to start the bubble, since the program gets paused when using `win32api` and tkinter will react with being unresponsive.

Note: this guide is specifically designed for python 3 since many of the modules are named differently in python 2.

Comment: The first one was exactly what I wanted. Tkanks! Now coping and pasting it makes me feel like a fool but i will do it :D The Second one is what I need sometimes. But I always created it myself. I will remember this. Thanks again!

Comment: But a problem: when my program shows a notification with code you gave, my program stops responding! Why? How to fix it?

Comment: Is it a tkinter program by chance?

Comment: Yepp. Everything made with tkinter3.

Comment: @mbilal25tryou will have to use some sort of threading to make it work...see my edit

Comment: So do I have to do all GUI with win32api then?

Comment: no, definitely not (to be honest, I don't like using win32api a lot either), just do what I said in the edit and your code will run as normal.

Comment: I think your edit came later somehow. I heard threading and I knew I will need it with GUI apps. I guess this is when. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

All possible widgets offered by tkinter are offered on their site.
As far as I am aware no bubbles exist and a label is the closest thing.
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm

One possible solution:

```
import os
import time
from tkinter import *


fname = "C:\\Users\\...\\test.txt"


while not a:
    time.sleep(1)
    a = os.path.isfile(fname) 


def Notification(master):

    w = Label(master, text="Hello, world!")
    w.pack()
    mainloop()


master = Tk()
Notification(master)
```

Here you have a while loop checking if you have added a new file. You can change the name dynamically if you want. Once the file is found, a tkinter widget pops up. You can change the location where the widget pops up.

Comment: I finally understood what you mean now because of my bad English and bad library knowing. But this is not what I really want. My app is some kind of toolbar at right side of screen with buttons only. They are shortcuts and one of them takes Screenshots. No place for one widget except a button. Well I could create but would not make sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But you can have the button popup and delete itself after 5 seconds.
Look into the "after" function of tkinter